# access $(this) with href="javascript:..." in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery. I call a JavaScript function with next html:

```
<li><span><a href="javascript:uncheckEl('tagVO-$id')">$tagname</a></span></li>
```

I would like to remove the `li` element and I thought this would be easy with the `$(this)` object. This is my JavaScript function:

```
function uncheckEl(id) {
    $("#"+id+"").attr("checked","");
    $("#"+id+"").parent("li").css("color","black");                 
    $(this).parent("li").remove();  // This is not working
    retrieveItems();
}
```

But `$(this)` is undefined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this (e.g. to hide the `<li>`):

```
function unCheckEl(id, ref) {
  (...)
  $(ref).parent().parent().hide(); // this should be your <li>
}
```

And your link:

```
<a href="javascript:uncheckEl('tagVO-$id', \$(this))">
```

`$(this)` is not present inside your function, because how is it supposed to know where the action is called from? You pass no reference in it, so `$(this)` could refer to everything but the `<a>`.

Comment: \ is not necessary
 
This works: 

<a href="javascript:uncheckEl('tagVO-$id', $(this))">

Comment: Hehe... I wasn't sure about escaping it. I look for the \ so long on my mac keyboard. It was sorta annoying. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like:

```
<li id="uncheck_tagVO-$id">$tagname</li>
```

and

```
$('li').click( function() {
    var id = this.id.split("_")[1];
    $('#'+id).attr("checked","").parent("li").css("color","black"); 
    $(this).remove();
    retrieveItems();
});
```

Comment: To make it simpler, you could also use `<li class="uncheck_tagVO" id="$id">` and on the jQuery you drop the 2nd line with replacing the 1st and 3rd line selectors to `$('li.uncheck_tagVO')` and `$('#'+this.id)`.